# Using react-i18next with ant design Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using react-18next I have to wrap the component like this

```
export default translate(['common', 'user', 'validation'], {wait: true})(MyComponent);
```

But antdesign form has already wrap the component
https://ant.design/components/form/

```
const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create()(NormalLoginForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, mountNode);
```

So I want to use react-18next with antdesign form, I did like this

```
export default translate(['common', 'user', 'validation'], {wait: true})(Form.create()(LoginForm));
```

And I got this error (typescript)

```
TS2559: Type '{ onSubmit: (username: any, password: any) => void; clearError: () => void; isProcessing: ...' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<Pick<any, never>, never> & Translat...'.
```

LoginForm.ts

```
interface Props {
  onSubmit(username, password);
  clearError;
  isProcessing;
  form;
  error;
  t?;
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component<Props, any> {}
```

Could you help me how to fix this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can check [Ant Design document](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/docs/react/i18n.en-US.md).

Comment: the example is using react-intl but my project use react-18next

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recompose` package.

https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Then do something like this:

```js
import { compose} from 'recompose'

{...}

export default compose(translate(['common', 'user', 'validation'], {wait: true}))(Form.create()(LoginForm));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any package you can do it by importing this:

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
```

and then exporting the component like so:

```
export default Form.create()(withTranslation()(EquipmentForm))
```